# FileSystemWatcher in an AspNetCore 2.1 BackgroundService\IHostedService

Tags: asp.net-core, filesystemwatcher, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying to use an implementation of the `BackgroundService` in an AspNet Core 2.1 application. I create a FileSystemWatcher in `ExecuteAsync` and link the associated events,however, the fsw events are either never fired (unreachable? already disposed?) or its some thing I am doing wrong with this being async or the scope is messed up. I can't seem to figure it out. Following is the relevant code.

```
public class FSWImpl : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;
    private readonly ILogger<LiftAndShift> _logger;
    private FileSystemWatcher _fsw;

    public LiftAndShift(IHostingEnvironment env, ILogger<FSWImpl> logger)
    {
        _env = env;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Creating new FSW");
        var path = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "WebData");
        _fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(path,"*.json");
        _fsw.Created += _fsw_Created;
        _fsw.Changed += _fsw_Changed;
        _fsw.Renamed += _fsw_Renamed;
        _fsw.Error += _fsw_Error;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void _fsw_Error(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e) => _logger.LogInformation("File error");
    private void _fsw_Renamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e) => _logger.LogInformation("File Renamed");
    private void _fsw_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) => _logger.LogInformation("File changed");
    private void _fsw_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) => _logger.LogInformation("File created");
}
```

I register this service in startup as `services.AddHostedService<FSWImpl>();`

Comment: Does that work? The services.AddHostedService<FSWImpl>(); will add it as Transient which destroy the FSWImpl and hence the FileSystemWatcher objects soon after ExecuteAsync returns. Thus, the file will no more be watched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For enabling `FileSystemWatcher`, you need to set `EnableRaisingEvents` as `True`.

Demo Code:

```
        protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Creating new FSW");
        var path = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "WebData");
        _fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(path, "*.json");
        _fsw.Created += _fsw_Created;
        _fsw.Changed += _fsw_Changed;
        _fsw.Renamed += _fsw_Renamed;
        _fsw.Error += _fsw_Error;
        _fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

`FileSystemWatcher.cs`

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets a value indicating whether the component is enabled.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     true if the component is enabled; otherwise, false. The default is false. If
    //     you are using the component on a designer in Visual Studio 2005, the default
    //     is true.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   T:System.ObjectDisposedException:
    //     The System.IO.FileSystemWatcher object has been disposed.
    //
    //   T:System.PlatformNotSupportedException:
    //     The current operating system is not Microsoft Windows NT or later.
    //
    //   T:System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
    //     The directory specified in System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.Path could not be found.
    //
    //   T:System.ArgumentException:
    //     System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.Path has not been set or is invalid.
    public bool EnableRaisingEvents { get; set; }
```